# Can't align vertically in div with inline Bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wrote a small Angular directive that generates a step input control for numbers. I've used Bootstrap buttons (`xs`) for the inc/dec controls and somehow managed to simulate a fake focus on the outer container. The problem is centring vertically the spans and the input in a stable layout that keeps together when zoomed.

This is the directive template:

```
<ng-form name="stepNumberForm" novalidate \>
    <div class="step-number"
        tabindex="{{$id}}"
        ng-class="{\'fake-focus\': fakeFocus}"
        ng-keyup="keyControl($event)">
        <span
            ng-disabled="incDisable"
            class="btn-primary"
            ng-click="inc()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus ">
            </i>
        </span>
         <input type="text"
                ng-style="setWidth()"
                name="value"
                ng-keyup="keyControl($event)"
                ng-model="value"
                ng-focus="selectAll($event)"
                ng-blur="validate()"
                class="input-xs">
        <span
            ng-disabled="decDisable"
            class="btn-primary"
            ng-click="dec()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

The CSS I've used is:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
.step-number{
    border:1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.input-xs {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border:none;
    line-height: 1em;
    height:1.1em;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.step-number span{
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.step-number span:first-child{
    margin-left: 1px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
.step-number span:last-child{
    margin-right: 1px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

.input-xs:focus{
    outline:none;
}
.step-number:focus{
    outline:none;
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);

}

.fake-focus{
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
.step-date{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The whole project is available at [github](https://github.com/vladblindu/stepper).
There is also a [working demo](http://www.stepper.blinduben.ro) and it's available for install through `$ bower install stepper`

I would greatly appreciate a helping hand from anybody finding this useful. All contributors are welcome to make this small directive look good. This means: input centred vertically, buttons centred vertically, a `1px` border padding inside the element, cross-browser stable and zoom stable.

Comment: I modified the template and got rid of the button, left the span only with button class on it and generated a huge amount of css to make it look decent, but it feels kind of "hackish". I won't post the answer since I hope there is a better one available for sure, myself being a beginner in web-development with veery little css experience.

Answer (score 0):

I've added these CSS rules at the **span** or the **button** element that has the `+` sign:

```
padding: 1px;
position: relative;
top: -1px;
```

It seems to be working just fine (I've also tried resizing the viewport - tested with Firefox).

Here is a screenshot of the outcome (*remember, only applied to the plus sign*)
[image: solution-screenshot]

You could add the above rules to a class `.stepper-buttons` and add it to the **span** or the **button** element (tested with both).

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: I would gladly approve your answer and I definitely appreciate your effort and time, but it looks like it's not a bullet-proof solution on the long run. On the other hand, I realised I stick to the "button" element for no particular reason. So, while testing your solution, I thought I could use a simple div or even the span element and apply the btn-primary class and implement a disabled state. I will do the changes and maybe you could support me in testing the css. (this could improve the corner radius for the buttons also - rounded on left and right separately) Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: @vladblindu It's ok, no problem in that :) Yes, I also thought that something was wrong with the `button` in `span` technique. Hope you can manage it, if there is something else you need, you could edit this question or add a new one. Good luck :)

Comment: I made some changes to the template and took out the button. I insetrted the input element in another div trying to normalise the display mode. If you check the www.stepper.blinduben.ro link you'll see a blue background  around the input element. I definitely can't understand why it's displaying like that.(the blue is the bck colour of the div containing the input).I don't know much about css, it's true, but this weird. By the way, if you think this little widget might be of use to anybody I would be very happy if you could become a contributor and fix the css. Thanks again.

Comment: @vladblindu I cannot see the blue background now, it seems to me like before (also the html code is the same :$). Do you mean the blue glow effect that appears when you type in a number? Well the thing is that I don't really have much time now, but I would be glad to help for something specific here :)

Comment: I've been away for some time and left this unanswered. Chris, thanks again for your time. Finally I had to do it!. Dive into bootstrap less variables and connect the whole css of the directive to bootstrap 3. If you ever want to see how this ended take a ride on github at git@github.com:vladblindu/stepper.git.

Comment: No problem @vladblindu! Glad you achieved what you had in mind :) I've checked the website again, it looks good!